# React-Native-Vision-Camera crashes upon calling Camera.requestCameraPermission

Tags: react-native

When I call Camera.requestPhotoPermission, the app crashes without any error codes, including if I try and wrap it in a try/catch block. I've never see anything quit out of an app like this before. Any ideas on what might be causing it? Camera.getPhotoPermission works fine.

Target IOS in podfiles 11.0, running on Xcode iPhone13 IOS v15.4

I tried following the instructions [here](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/troubleshooting) such as creating the bridge file in the root of ios

```
package.json
"dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.67.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.67.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
```

Comment: Hello Brandon, did you get any solution?